# Syntax Error when executing shell script with java

Tags: shell, apache-commons, processbuilder

I have a shell script which I want to execute within a Java class. The shell script takes an input file and produces an output file from it.

To execute it, I use apache commons exec. Here's my little code:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("/bin/sh ./generate_void_description.sh ./n3file ./voidfile");

int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

As a Result i get this Error Message :

```
./generate_void_description.sh: 44: ./generate_void_description.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
```

Of course I can read and I understand that the message means that there's a syntax Error in the script but.

1) I didnt write the script and I'm not familiar with bash script syntax
2) The script works perfectly without any errors when I run it on a terminal within ubuntu

Has it something to do with User rights ? I need to create an output file maybe I don't have the permissions to do this if if

Comment: Please post line 44 of the script. My guess is that the script is written in bash and uses an array, which won't work with '/bin/sh'.

Comment: line 44 : declare -a map_pred_type=($(cat $ntriples | sed '/^ *#/d;/^ *$/d' | awk '{

Comment: Are you certain that `/bin/sh` is equivalent to `/bin/bash` on your system? It frequently is, but that's not universal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script uses bash features, most noticeably an array in line 44. You'll have to execute the script using `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the bash script is exiting with a return code of 2.  If that's normal, try this before making the execute call.

```
executor.setExitValue(2);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried this but it won't work :(
No output file is produced and I get the same error message : ./generate_void_description.sh: 44:    ./generate_void_description.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected